# Getting error 'Expected undefined to be true' in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, html, angular, jasmine

Writing a test case for service function which should  return true value.But i am getting error "Expected undefined to be true".below is the code for the same.

This is landingpage.serviice.spec.ts

```
import {Card} from "../../../shared/components/card/card.model";
import {} from 'jasmine';
import {LandingPageService} from "../../../features/admin/landing-page/landing-page.service";
import {ComponentFixture, TestBed} from "@angular/core/testing";
import {GBHttpClient, GBHttpClientCreator} from './../../../blocks/global/http-client';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Principal,TokenService} from "../../../shared/auth";
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {MockRouter} from "../../../test-helpers/mock-route.service";
import {NgbModule} from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";
import {NgXTestModule} from "../../../test.module";
import {HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController} from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import {MockBridgeService} from "../../../test-helpers/mock-bridge.service";
import {MockPrincipalService} from "../../../test-helpers/mock-principal.service";
import {TranslateService} from "@ngx-translate/core";
import {QuickTranslateService} from "../../../shared/services/quick-translate.service";
import {ParamsService} from './../../../shared/services/params.service';
import {SearchService} from "../../../features/search";
import {SpinnerService} from './../../../shared/spinner/spinner.service';
import {Observable,of} from 'rxjs';


describe('LandingPageService', () => {
  // let result : boolean;
  let landingPageService = {
    checkLimitOrderFeatureEnabled: jasmine.createSpy(),
    // checkItemCategoryLimit:jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue(of(null))
  }
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController;


  beforeEach(async() => {
    const mockPrincipal = new MockPrincipalService();
    const mockRouter = new MockRouter();
    const mockBridgeService = new MockBridgeService();
    const searchService = new SearchService(null, null);

    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        NgXTestModule,
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        NgbModule.forRoot()
      ],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: Principal,
          useValue: mockPrincipal
        },
        {
          provide: Router,
          useValue: mockRouter
        },
        {
          provide: "SearchService",
          useValue: searchService
        },
        {
          provide: "BridgeService",
          useValue: mockBridgeService
        },
        LandingPageService,
        TokenService,
        QuickTranslateService,
        TranslateService,
        ParamsService,
        SpinnerService,
        {
          provide: GBHttpClient,
          useFactory: GBHttpClientCreator,
          deps: [HttpClient]
        }
      ]
    })
    landingPageService = TestBed.get(LandingPageService); 
    // result = false;
    httpMock = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);

  });

  afterEach(() => {
    TestBed.resetTestingModule();
    httpMock.verify();
  }); 




    it('should get Limit Order feature toggle value', () => {
        spyOn(landingPageService,'checkLimitOrderFeatureEnabled').and.callThrough();
        expect(landingPageService).toBeTruthy();
        let result = landingPageService.checkLimitOrderFeatureEnabled();
        expect(result).toBe(true);
      });
    
    
    });
```

This is landing-page.service.ts

```
checkLimitOrderFeatureEnabled() {
      return this.principal.getUserContext().enableLimitOrder && this.principal.getUserContext().enableLimitOrderParameter;
    }
```

For this function which is written in landingpage service i need to write test case.

Comment: Please provide sufficient information so that someone can help you. Below things are not clear to me :
1. Which is the function you are calling inside " should get Limit Order feature toggle value " spec ?
2. Why you are expecting generalCarouselService service itself to be true?
3. Please clearly mention the service function definition you want to test and the spec you have written and the expectation of spec as well.

Thanks.

Comment: I have edited the question and code kindly look into it.

Comment: Can you remove first 2 line in spec (        spyOn(landingPageService,'checkLimitOrderFeatureEnabled').and.callThrough();
        expect(landingPageService).toBeTruthy();) and test it. Both the lines are not required. Also, please do post the error if it didn't worked. Thanks.